# Perl - Abort upload using CGI

Tags: perl, file-upload, cgi

I am writing a file management application in Perl, PHP, and JavaScript (jQuery) and I would like to give the user the ability to cancel their upload.

Here's some background infos: 
When the user chooses to upload a file, I change the target of the form to an iFrame, which posts to the perl script. Within the script, I update a row in the database that shows the current status of the upload. The status could be `success`, `error`, `initializing`, `abort`, or `expired`. When the status is `abort`, I would like to stop the upload completely.

Is there a way to kill off this script from within the hook? (So that I don't have to wait for the whole file.) On a side note, the `-e $filepath` works, but it still loops through the whole file, so the message won't display until afterwards. In either case, I would just like the script to completely stop.

**Added some more code:**

Perl:

```
my $cgi = CGI->new(\&hook, \%data, 0);

sub hook { 
    my $status = GetStatus();

    if(-e $$data{filepath} and $status eq "initializing"){
        # send JSON back to browser
        # insert your amazing snippet here
        ... 
    }

    if($status eq "success"){
        # continue writing file to disk
        # update db
        ... 
    }

    if($status eq "abort"){
        # cancel the upload
        # insert your amazing snippet here
        ... 
    }

}
```

HTML:

```
<iframe id="upload_target" onload="uploadDone();"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#upload_form').submit(function(data){
    window.setInterval('doProgress()', 250);
});

function doProgress() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
        success: function(data){
            json = $.parseJSON(data);
            if(json.status != null){
                // json.message contains the percentage number
                $("#progressbar").reportprogress(json.message);
            }
        }
    });
}

function uploadDone() { 
    var ret = $('#upload_target').contents().find('body').text();
    var json = jQuery.parseJSON(ret);

    if(json.status != null){
        $.modal.close();
        show_message(json);
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
I saw somewhere on Google that aborting the request through javascript might be the way to solve the problem. Can anyone say for sure whether this is true? What it entails is simply assigning the request to a variable, then calling the abort() method on it, ex: `xhr.abort();`

Comment: Do I need to rephrase the question?

Comment: Maybe...I'm still not clear on exactly what you're asking for. Are you looking for a way to abort a CGI request based on some data fetched from a database? Or are you looking for a way for one CGI request to be able to interrupt another that may still be in progress? Or some third thing?

Comment: @Dan: The first one `:)`

Comment: Are you sure? Sorry, on second reading of the code it looks like you have some other process executing the upload in the background, and what you want to do is have a second request running four times a second that checks the status and then does something based on the current value of the database. Am I wrong here?

Comment: @Dan: You are correct. Inside the hook, I check the status, and do what needs to be done based on said status :) OP updated with new information - possibly shedding light on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know without sourcediving exactly how `CGI` is handling the upload and calling the hook function, but my first attempt to stop the upload would be to close STDIN.

Comment: Are you running under mod_perl, or straight CGI?

Comment: No mod_perl here. Just straight CGI. OP updated with new information - possibly shedding light on my problem.

Comment: I faked a click of the `ESC` key to abort STDIN +1